# query mobile 1.4.0 application select2 plugin is not working how to resolve

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-select2

We are **developing Hybrid mobile application using jquery mobile 1.4.0**. In this project have **so many select menu list**, that select fields are few are short list and few are long list. What ever long or short select menu list **we have to show in Filterable inside select menu list only**.

So that requirement **we are using  [select2 plugin](https://select2.github.io/) in my project**. But it is **not happening anything default jquery mobile select menu is showing**, but **sample project is working fine** what ever we have the requirement that is exactly coming but in **my project same steps i followed but not happening** anything why don't no.

We Don't want Jquery Mobile Select menu List widget we need only Select2 Plugin.

Any one please help me where i am missing what i have to follow , we are now ending stag of the project.

Error is coming like this below

**$(...).select2 is not a function**

**screen shots**

[image]

**My Project Code**

```html
<!--- Index.html --->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Project</title>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="loadcss" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="loadcss1" />
<script src="dist/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="lib/jquery-mobile/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="lib/jquery-mobile-router/js/jquery.mobile.router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="lib/jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="lib/jquery-mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
 
<link href="dist/css/select2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<script
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2VMMoklmxRaYy1NvJ1Et8PjF2h4mcZEM"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepickerr.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepickertheme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wickedpicker.css"> 
<script src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/wickedpicker.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="display: none;">

  <!--- Login--->
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div id="loadhome">
   <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin-top:31px;background: transparent !important;">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 

  <div data-role="page" id="lang">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin-top:34%;background: transparent !important;">
 <div class="text-center bottomspacer">
  <img src="img/logo.png" width="30%">
 </div>

 <h2 class="text-center bottomspacer" >Choose Preferred Language</h2>
 <h4 class="text-center bottomspacer" >Ø§Ø®ØªÙØ§Ø± Ø§ÙÙØºØ© Ø§ÙÙÙØ¶ÙØ©</h4>
 
 
 <div style="width:100%">
  <span class="english" id="langEn" onclick="navToLogin('login','en')" style="float:left ">English</span>
  <span class="qatra" id="langAr" onclick="navToLogin('login','ar')" style="float:right ">Ø§ÙØ¹Ø±Ø¨ÙØ©</span>
 </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="login">
  <div id="loadlogin"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="reg">
  <div id="loadreg"></div>
  <div align="center">
   <div data-role="popup" id="uploadreg" data-overlay-theme="b"
    class="popUpDiv" style="left: 0% !important;" data-theme="a"
    data-corners="false" align="center">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="popupReg" class="popUpUi"
     data-inset="true">
     <li onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);" class="popUpLi">
      <label id="galleryreg" class="popUpLbl"
      style="margin-top: 16px; font-size: 25px !important; color: #a61735;"></label>
     </li>
     <li onclick="capturePhoto();" class="popUpLi2"><label
      id="capturereg" class="popUpLbl"
      style="margin-top: 16px; font-size: 25px !important; color: #a61735;"></label>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="dashbrd">
  <div id="loaddashbrd"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="vstrdashbrd">
  <div id="loadvstrdashbrd"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="mngprof">
  <div id="loadmngprof"></div>
  <div align="center">
   <div data-role="popup" id="uploadmngprof" data-overlay-theme="b"
    class="popUpDiv" style="left: 0% !important;" data-theme="a"
    data-corners="false" align="center">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="popupmngprof" class="popUpUi"
     data-inset="true">
     <li onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);" class="popUpLi">
      <label id="gallerymngprof" class="popUpLbl"
      style="margin-top: 16px; font-size: 25px !important; color: #a61735;"></label>
     </li>
     <li onclick="capturePhoto();" class="popUpLi2"><label
      id="capturemngprof" class="popUpLbl"
      style="margin-top: 16px; font-size: 25px !important; color: #a61735;"></label>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="policy">
  <div id="loadpolicy"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="benefitlimitspol">
  <div id="loadbenefitlimitspol"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="healthcertpol">
  <div id="loadhealthcertpol"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="insurancecard">
  <div id="loadinsurancecard"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="srvc">
  <div id="loadsrvc"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="emgcyno">
  <div id="loademgcyno"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="bmicaltr">
  <div id="loadbmicaltr"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="hlthtips">
  <div id="loadhlthtips"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="mediRem">
  <div id="loadmediRem" class="calOpacity"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="showNotifications">
  <div id="loadshowNotifications"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="clms">
  <div id="loadclms"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="clmsSub">
  <div id="loadclmsSub" class="calOpacity"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="clmstrkng">
  <div id="loadclmstrkng"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="clmsexp">
  <div id="loadclmsexp"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="preaprvl">
  <div id="loadpreaprvl" class="calOpacity"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="preaprovaltracking">
  <div id="loadpreaprovaltracking"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="pharmacy">
  <div id="loadpharmacy"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="hlthrcrds">
  <div id="loadhlthrcrds" class="calOpacity"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="shwtrkdtls">
  <div id="loadshwtrkdtls"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="provider">
  <div id="loadprovider"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="providerlist">
  <div id="loadproviderlist"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="providerdetails">
  <div id="loadproviderdetails"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="prvdrsshowonmap">
  <div id="loadprvdrsshowonmap"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="prvdrsMap">
  <div id="loadprvdrsMap"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="about">
  <div id="loadabout"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="contactus">
  <div id="loadcontactus"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="help">
  <div id="loadhelp"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="chat">
  <div id="loadchat"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div data-role="page" id="pushNotifications">
  <div id="loadpushNotifications"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="popup" id="upload" data-overlay-theme="b"
  class="popUpDiv" style="left: 0% !important;" data-theme="a"
  data-corners="false" align="center">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="" data-inset="true" class="popUpUi">
   <li class="popUpLi" id="clmGal"
    onclick="getSavedDoc(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);">
    <label id="gallery" class="popUpLbl"
    style="margin-top: 16px; font-size: 25px !important; color: #a61735; padding-top: 9px;"></label>
   </li>
   <li class="popUpLi2" id="clamCam"
    onclick="getSavedDoc(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);">
    <label id="capture" class="popUpLbl"
    style="margin-top: 16px; font-size: 25px !important; color: #a61735; padding-top: 9px;"></label>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnRefNo">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnCustCode">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnTransId">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrCode">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrName">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrFax">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrPhone">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrAddrs01">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrAddrs02">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrAddrs03">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrLng">
 <input type="hidden" name="text" id="txtHdnPrvdrLat">
 
 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/fastclick/js/fastclick.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="lib/handlebars/js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 
 <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-gauge.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/navigation.js"></script>
 <script src="js/common.js"></script>
 <script src="js/login.js"></script>
 <script src="js/reg.js"></script>
 <script src="js/langpreffer.js"></script>
 <script src="js/mngprof.js"></script>
 <script src="js/dashbrd.js"></script>
 <script src="js/policy.js"></script>
 <script src="js/benefitlimitspol.js"></script>
 <script src="js/clmsexp.js"></script>
 <script src="js/clmssub.js"></script>
 <script src="js/clmstrkng.js"></script>
 <script src="js/preaprvl.js"></script>
 <script src="js/preaprovaltracking.js"></script>
 <script src="js/phamcy.js"></script>
 <script src="js/healthcertpol.js"></script>
 <script src="js/insurancecard.js"></script>
 <script src="js/hlthrcrds.js"></script>
 <script src="js/prvdr.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bmicaltr.js"></script>
 <script src="js/emgcyno.js"></script>
 <script src="js/hlthtips.js"></script>
 <script src="js/prvdrslistdtls.js"></script>
 <script src="js/showmaps.js"></script>
 <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
 <script src="js/pushnotification.js"></script>
  <script src="js/mediRem.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

```js
/*Login.js*/

$(".js-example-responsive").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state",
  language: "es",
   theme: "classic"
});
```

```html
<!---Login.html--->

<select class="js-example-responsive" style="width: 50%">
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
 <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
 <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
 <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
 <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
 <option value="NY">New York</option>
 <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
 <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
 <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
 <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
 <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
 <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
 <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
 <option value="WA">Washington</option>
 <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<select class="js-example-responsive" style="width: 50%">
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
 <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
 <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
 <option value="ME">Maine</option>
 <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
 <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
 <option value="WA">Washington</option>
 <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
     
<select class="js-example-responsive" style="width: 50%">
 <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
 <option value="ME">Maine</option>
 <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
 <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
</select>
```

**Sample Project code**

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your answer below so that if other encounter the same issue then they will have this resource.

Comment: Shore Elliot, but i am facing one more issue that's why i am not posted the answer.

Comment: I am success fully showing seletc2 but when i wrote select menu in index html page only i see when ever i wrote in other html page it is not coming i am trying to resolving